# Autostart Script for Docker Container

Tags: docker, debian

I want a script that starts if my container start in docker. I have a starter.sh and a dockerfile.

I tried to change the command but it is the same or it didnt work. The file copy of the starter.sh works and it runs.

In my Dockerfile is this code

```
COPY starter.sh /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN /etc/init.d/starter.sh
```

In my starter.sh

```
update-rc.d starter defaults
echo "Hello"
```

This is the message that comes if it runs the starter.sh

```
usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> defaults
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
                -n: not really
                -f: force

The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future.
Hello
```

I hope someone could help me

Comment: Init scripts don't really work in Docker.  Usually if you need to run two processes, the preferred approach is to run them in two separate containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only put the

```
update-rc.d starter defaults
```

in my dockerfile from my script.